# Insert data into vector

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, stl, split

I have a .txt file with data in the following format:

```
1.23,2.34,3.45
4.56,5.67,6.78
```

How to insert the numbers in a vector

```
vector[1]={1.23,4.56,...}
vector[2]={2.34,5.67,...}
vector[3]={3.45,6.78,...}
```

Code

```
ifstream in("data.txt");
vector<vector<int> > v;

if (in) {
    string line;
    while (getline(in,line)) {
        v.push_back(std::vector<int>());
        stringstream split(line);
        int value;
        while (split >> value)
            v.back().push_back(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What it is that you don't like about your code? Does it work?

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have? How does this differ from what you want?

Comment: You need to create a `std::vector<float> vv` instead of `v.push_back(std::vector<int>());` and push the `value` into that vector which is `vv`. After second while you can add that vector `vv` to the main vector. But of course if this is what you meant.

Comment: @MahanGM He is reading floating point values from the file :)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems in your code

1. Your inner `vector` should be a `vector` of `float` or `double` instead of `int`.
2. Your `value` variable should also be `float` or `double`
3. You need to go past the separator(comma) while reading.
4. You need to create as many inner vectors as there are values in each line. I have done this below by having a boolean `first` variable - I use this to make sure I create vectors only while reading the first line.
5. The index of the inner vector to `push_back` to is the same as the column number of the value on the line being pushed back. I use a variable `col` to figure out what is the column number being read on a line currently.

You need as many inner vectors as the number of columns. Each of your inner vectors has as many members as the numbers of lines in your file.

```
ifstream in("data.txt");
vector<vector<double> > v;

bool first = false;
if (in) 
{
    string line;
    while (getline(in,line)) 
    {
        istringstream split(line);
        double value;
        int col = 0;
        char sep;

        while (split >> value)
        {
            if(!first)
            {
                // Each new value read on line 1 should create a new inner vector
                v.push_back(std::vector<double>());
            }

            v[col].push_back(value);
            ++col;

            // read past the separator                
            split>>sep;
        }

        // Finished reading line 1 and creating as many inner
        // vectors as required            
        first = true;
    }

}
```